# Out of bounds exception when started using enums

Tags: java, enums, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to have a program that maps terrain in java. Just now it's flagging an error in the main program:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at Map.run(Map.java:35)
>       at Terrain.run(Terrain.java:31)
>       at Terrain.main(Terrain.java:10)

I've just started using enum and it's only started t flag up when I implemented some into my code. Here is the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Terrain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Terrain t = new Terrain();

        t.init();
        t.run();//Flags here
    }
    private Map map;

    public void init()
    {
        map = new Map();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a height");
        map.setHeight(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please enter a width");
        map.setWidth(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please enter a hedge size");
        map.setHedgeSize(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Please enter an entrance size");
        map.setEntranceSize((in.nextInt()/2));
        in.close();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        map.run();//And flags here
    }
}
```

And heres the map class:

```
public class Map {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int area;
    private int passCount;
    private int hedgeSize;
    private int entranceSize;
    private int percentageOfPassable;
    TerrainType [][] terrain;
    TerrainType tile;

    public Map()
    {
    height=0;
    width=0;
    area=0;
    passCount=0;
    hedgeSize=0;
    entranceSize=0;
    percentageOfPassable=0;
    terrain = new TerrainType[width][height];

    }
    public void run()
    {
        for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
        {
            String mapDisplay = new String();
            for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
            {
                area++; 
                terrain[x][y]=TerrainType.GRASS;
                if (x<hedgeSize||x>((width-1)-hedgeSize))
                {
                    terrain[x][y]=TerrainType.HEDGE;
                }
                if (y<hedgeSize||y>((height-1)-hedgeSize))
                {
                    terrain[x][y]=TerrainType.HEDGE;
                }//Sets border with regard to hedge size
                if (y>((height-1)-hedgeSize))
                {
                    if (x>=((width/2)-entranceSize)&&x<((width/2)+entranceSize))
                    {
                        terrain[x][y]=TerrainType.GRASS;
                    }
                }//Entrance size+position with regard to hedge size

                if(terrain[x][y].getTerrainPassable())
                {
                    passCount++;
                    terrain[x][y]=TerrainType.GRASS;
                }
                mapDisplay+=terrain[x][y].getChar();
            }
            System.out.println(mapDisplay);
        }//End nested for loop to set initial values
        percentageOfPassable=passCount*100/area;
        System.out.println(percentageOfPassable+"%");
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this.height=height;
    }
    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this.width=width;
    }
    public void setEntranceSize(int entranceSize)
    {
        this.entranceSize=entranceSize;
    }
    public void setHedgeSize(int hedgeSize)
    {
        this.hedgeSize=hedgeSize;
    }
}
```

And finally my enum:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public enum TerrainType
{
    GRASS(',', true, Color.GREEN), ROCK('#', false, Color.GRAY),
    HEDGE('H', false, Color.YELLOW), WATER('W', false, Color.BLUE);
     private char terrainChar;
     private boolean terrainPassable;
     private Color colour;

     private TerrainType(char terrainChar, boolean terrainPassable, Color colour) {
            this.terrainChar = terrainChar;
            this.terrainPassable = terrainPassable;
            this.colour = colour;
        }

        public char getChar() {
            return terrainChar;
        }
        public boolean getTerrainPassable() {
            return terrainPassable;
        }
        public Color getColour() {
            return colour;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not connected with enums. See at exception, it says: *Array Index Out Of Bounds*, it means that you use negative or too big number as array index. Check it out with debugger.

Comment: Unfortunatly not the new code is in the enum and map. The main program was running fine up untill I added the enum in

Comment: So, what about debugger? Which line causes exception?

Comment: As soon as you said it Weiest, I knew you were right. Tried, tested and worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to your terrain is initialized as TerrainType[0][0] in the constructor which results in a empty array and wasn't reinitialized later during run() after the user input their desired values hence it stays as an empty array.

```
height = 0;
width = 0;
terrain = new TerrainType[width][height];
```

You can move it to your run() method on your Map.java instead so that i would generate a array with the size specified by the user.

```
public void run() {
    terrain = new TerrainType[width][height];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Following answer is not related to OP's case. 

But related to the question title.*

- this may happen if you have **an `enum` that is Empty**.

---

misc

<sub>- (Which throws this exception: )

  ```
     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
      at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.fromOrdinal(EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.java:76)
  ```
- (Another post that is in a more *general* case -- simply due to *more enum value* (in ordinal, not string) than the database schema expected: ) 
  [How to fix "nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2" in a Spring Boot - postgresql Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602802/how-to-fix-nested-exception-is-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-index)</sub>