# How to fix "nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2" in a Spring Boot - postgresql Project

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Project with PostgreSQL and when I try to execute the findAll() method from the UserController I get the error. You can see my User Class and the error that I get back, it has to do with the query but I cant find it. Also I use a UserRepository that extends JpaRepository I can execute the method findById but I have this problem in findAll().

```
package com.application.vehicleRepairShop.domain;


@Entity

@Table(name = "users", schema = "vehicleproject")

public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "afm")
private int afm;

@Column(name = "role_id")
private UserType type;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

public User(){}

public User(long id, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, int afm, UserType type, List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.type = type;
    this.vehicles = vehicles;
}

public User(long id, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, int afm, UserType type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.type = type;
    this.vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}

public User(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String address, int afm, UserType type) {

    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.afm = afm;
    this.type = type;
    this.vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
}


public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
    return vehicles;
}

public void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {

    this.vehicles = vehicles;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getAfm() {
    return afm;
}

public void setAfm(int afm) {
    this.afm = afm;
}

public UserType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(UserType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void addVehicleToList(Vehicle vehicle){
    this.vehicles.add(vehicle);
}

public void removeVehicleFromUserList(Vehicle vehicle){
    this.vehicles.remove(vehicle);
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", afm=" + afm +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", vehicles=" + vehicles +
            '}';
}
}
```

ENUM

```
public enum UserType {
    ADMIN(1),
    USER(2);

    private int code;

    UserType(int code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

SQL TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE vehicleproject."roles" (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT role_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into vehicleproject."roles"
("name")
values
('ADMIN'),
('USER')

--USERS TABLE-----
------------------

CREATE TABLE vehicleproject."users" (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NULL,
    "password" varchar(255) NULL,
    first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    afm int8 NULL,
    role_id int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_email_key UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT user_role_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES vehicleproject."roles"(id)
);
```

ERROR

```
2019-06-14 19:56:33.678  INFO 13992 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-06-14 19:56:33.806  INFO 13992 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-06-14 19:56:33.850  INFO 13992 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-06-14 19:56:33.926  INFO 13992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final}
2019-06-14 19:56:33.927  INFO 13992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-06-14 19:56:34.064  INFO 13992 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-06-14 19:56:34.241  INFO 13992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2019-06-14 19:56:34.432  INFO 13992 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-06-14 19:56:34.434  INFO 13992 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@6c5ca0b6
2019-06-14 19:56:35.346  INFO 13992 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-06-14 19:56:35.904  INFO 13992 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-14 19:56:35.956  WARN 13992 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-06-14 19:56:36.284  INFO 13992 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-06-14 19:56:36.289  INFO 13992 --- [           main] c.a.v.VehicleRepairShopApplication       : Started VehicleRepairShopApplication in 5.695 seconds (JVM running for 6.765)
2019-06-14 19:56:40.761  INFO 13992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-14 19:56:40.762  INFO 13992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-06-14 19:56:40.773  INFO 13992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 11 ms
2019-06-14 19:56:40.845  INFO 13992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-06-14 19:56:40.966 DEBUG 13992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_,
        user0_.address as address2_0_,
        user0_.afm as afm3_0_,
        user0_.email as email4_0_,
        user0_.first_name as first_na5_0_,
        user0_.last_name as last_nam6_0_,
        user0_.password as password7_0_,
        user0_.role_id as role_id8_0_ 
    from
        vehicleproject.users user0_
2019-06-14 19:56:41.003 ERROR 13992 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2] with root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.fromOrdinal(EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.OrdinalEnumValueConverter.toDomainValue(OrdinalEnumValueConverter.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.OrdinalEnumValueConverter.readValue(OrdinalEnumValueConverter.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3010) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1746) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1561) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:306) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.application.vehicleRepairShop.service.UserServiceImpl.findAll(UserServiceImpl.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.application.vehicleRepairShop.controller.UserController.findAll(UserController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: The exception happens at EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.fromOrdinal. So my guess is that your role_id value in the database column is 2, but that there are only two values in the UserType enum (whose ordinals are thus 0 and 1).

Comment: @JBNizet , I edit my question with my enum class and the 2 tables  but I cannot understand the conflict. Could you please see it and tell me if you found something!

Comment: UserType has two values: ADMIN and USER. ADMIN's ordinal is 0, and USER's ordinal is 1. So if your row contains 2 in the user_type column, it's an invalid ordinal for the UserType enum. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @JBNizet Please post your comments as the answer. I'm really tired of reading unanswered questions where the answer is in the comment

Comment: @SimonMartinelli please how we can solve this problem ? I read somewhere that default ordinal cannot be changed ?

Comment: Please ask a new question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The exception happens at `EnumJavaTypeDescriptor.fromOrdinal`. So my guess is that your role_id value in the database column is 2.

But there are only two values in the UserType enum: ADMIN and USER. ADMIN's ordinal is 0, and USER's ordinal is 1. So if your row contains 2 in the user_type column, it's an invalid ordinal for the UserType enum.

Answer (score 0):

Pls Check your database value should be 0,1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).